# How to create (the missing) El Captain recovery partition?

Tags: bootcamp, disk-utility, partition, recovery

I upgraded from Snow Leopard to El Captain. 
Before upgrade I had a bootcamp partition, and a third FAT32 partition.
this caused some complications in the upgrade process and I had to delete the El Captain recovery partition (as well as my FAT32 partition).

Now I have two partitions: El Captain in my macintosh partition, and windows in my bootcamp partition, and everything is working fine.

Just that I do not have the El Captain Recovery Partition. Is there a way I can create it manually ? So that just in case something goes wrong I can recover.

(I know about the recovery USB stick, but I want to have recovery on the same HDD)

EDIT:
I re-installed the El Capitan. It went smooth. Now I have a 650MB recovery partition. Isn't it supposed to be 6 GB partition?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling OS X?

Comment: Do it only if it is absolutely necessary. There is always the internet based recovery in case something goes wrong and it doesn't take as much space.

Comment: Can you refresh the OS X 10.11 installation? What happens if you try to download El Captain and install from the App Store?

Comment: @Soroosh, how can I access internet recovery option when there is no recovery partition to boot system from?

Comment: I re-installed the El Capitan. It went smooth. Now I have a 650MB recovery partition. Isn't it supposed to be 6 GB partition? [question edited]

Comment: @cybergeek654 Internet recovery is always accessible whenever your recovery partition becomes corrupted. It is specifically designed for this situation. You can read more [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201314). However, this is a feature that is only available on newer macs.